# How to write the SQL query in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I want to write all the insert, select and delete queries in Visual Studio but I don't know how to write them.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=5CG50749V3\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO backup(Option,EquipmentID,SerialNumber,Description,Location,DueDate,DaytoDue,EquipmentWithdraworRemarks,NCRorOOTHistory,LastOOTissuanceDate,AvailableinSapphire,ResponsiblePerson,CalibrationOption,CalibrationSourceorLab,YearofManufacturing,ManufacturerorVendor,CalibrationCost,AssetNo,CalibrationTAT,SendInDate,Status), SELECT * FROM Equipment where (SerialNumber = '" + TextBox2.Text + "' or EquipmentID = '" + TextBox1.Text + "' ), DELETE FROM Equipment where (SerialNumber = '" + TextBox2.Text + "' or EquipmentID = '" + TextBox1.Text + "' )", con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Use parameters please...

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Use **Entity Framework** instead, and you won't have to write next to no SQL anymore yourself !

Comment: Also both `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` are `IDisposable` so you should consider using `using` on both of those variables.

Comment: what is parameter? sorry i'm still new for it.

Comment: I don't think that _Entity Framework_ supports the INSERT/SELECT pattern that he is using. I do suggest though, _never_ use insert / select *. Always use a field list, not *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using parameterized query like below:

```
string connectionstring = "Data Source=5CG50749V3\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {

                string sql = @"INSERT IntO [backup](Option,EquipmentID,SerialNumber,Description,Location,
                                DueDate,DaytoDue,EquipmentWithdraworRemarks,NCRorOOTHistory,LastOOTissuanceDate,
                                AvailableinSapphire,ResponsiblePerson,CalibrationOption,CalibrationSourceorLab,
                                YearofManufacturing,ManufacturerorVendor,CalibrationCost,AssetNo,CalibrationTAT,SendInDate,Status)
                                SELECT * FROM Equipment where SerialNumber = @serialnumber or EquipmentID = @equipmentId; 
                                DELETE FROM Equipment where SerialNumber = @serialnumber or EquipmentID = @equipmentId";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add("@serialnumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "testSerialNumber";
                    command.Parameters.Add("@equipmentId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "testequipmentid";
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                }

            }
```

Comment: @naz-Edyra , If any confusion please let me know.

Comment: for the insert query, actually I don't know the value for each column. The user will search the data based on the serial number or equipment id. so the data will appear based on it. but not all data will appear to user. Some data only stored in the sql server. however i want to move all the data that appear to the user and stored in sql server. so for the value, what should i put ? it is the column name? @Amir

Comment: So you wan to insert into table backup by selecting from the equipment table?

Comment: yeah exactly. but it according to the user.  for example if the user choose serial number or Equipment id A. all the data that related to A will be move to the backup table. i want to create button delete but instead delete the data, the data have been move to other table which is backup table. @Amir

Comment: one more question: Are columns name same in table Equipment and and BackUP?

Comment: Hey check out my new edit on answer. It will work perfectly for you. It will do all insert by selecting and delete from the equipment table that is inserter to back up.

Comment: sorry , can i ask. why for where condition, you use the SerialNumber instead of Textbox1.Text. can you explain about it? next, when i run the code it show the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Option'." @Amir

Comment: You can provide text box value like below.
command.Parameters.Add("@serialnumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Textbox1.Text; And keep option inside [] bracket like this [Option]. This might solve this error and make sure backup is also inside []

Comment: thank you Amir. The code work for me. Thank you so much. @Amir

Comment: You are wel-come. Make sure to upvote my answer when you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

The SqlCommand(String) method takes only one argument and initializes a new instance of the SqlCommand class with the text of the query.